# Failed prop type: Invalid prop of type `function` supplied expected a single ReactElement

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactive-programming

I'm trying to make a post using react v4 and axios, I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SX5HkOP-LWs&index=7&list=PLuNEz8XtB51K-x3bwCC9uNM_cxXaiCcRY) and I did exactly as he said, but I'm getting an error:
Maybe because I'm using another version of react, how can fix it?

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `userSignupRequest` of type `function`
>   supplied to `SignUp`, expected a single ReactElement.

**here is my code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import SignUpForm from './SignUpForm';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { userSignupRequest } from '../../actions/signupActions';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class SignUp extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const { userSignupRequest } = this.props;
    return(
        <SignUpForm userSignupRequest={userSignupRequest}/>
    );
  }
}


SignUp.propTypes = {
  userSignupRequest: PropTypes.element.isRequired
}

export default connect(null, { userSignupRequest })(SignUp);
```

**SignUp Actions:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Constants from '../components/Constants'

export function userSignupRequest(userData) {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post(Constants.URL_REGISTER, userData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you mean to have have `element` instead of `func` in your PropTypes?

```
SignUp.propTypes = {
  userSignupRequest: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Colin, I was coming here to delete that question, I just spotted the exactly error that you pointed out.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted! :)